# What is the prayaschitta for chanting the Gayatri Mantra without initiation?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, prayaschitta

Do scriptures mention any sort of prayaschitta for people who have chanted the Gayatri Mantra without initiation?

Comment: Does Gayatri Mantra need initiation, in first place?  Seems like freely available & recommended in modern times. Observed in many mobile ringtones & caller tunes!

Comment: @iammilind But don't scriptures say it shouldn't be chanted without initiation?

Comment: @Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury first of all which scriptures is there  smritis ofcourse they can be but god is one and for intance do rigveda where gayatri mantra first occoured give such a rule the rules in old days have gone if someone gonna teach manners to a girl like old now so there is no saying that he can be said 'stupid' :)

Comment: Yes, read in this site at many places about having an initiation before chanting a Mantra. But not sure if it applies in modern times when there is a lack of a genuine Guru, who determines disciple's worthiness & then selflessly initiates that disciple or rejects that disciple. In modern times one's own conscience is the most trustworthy Guru. Hence whether to chant a Mantra or not, has to be decided by oneself. When baba Ramdev came to our city, he mass initiated all fellows in Gayatri Mantra followed by Yogasana. Now who will decide if it's valid or not? Ppl will give only personal opinions.

Comment: @Fiercelord U seem to love Rig Veda right? So u know that each of the Mantras have a Rishi..what does that signify? That- God spoke and the Rishi heard.. This was the very first instance of the Mantra transfer.. And between whom it took place? Obviously between two **conscious beings** right? So, that's why everytime such a transfer were to occur in future it has to be between two conscious beings..when we take mantra from books, etc then the source is inanimate..that is one problem..moreover there are other problems too.. So, that's why Mantra Diksha is required....

Comment: Does Gayatri Mantra need initiation, in first place? --- Gayatri initiation is the Vedic initiation.. A student gets the right to study the Vedas only after this initiation.. @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross i did not said i love rigveda i love all veda but among them sama as lord krishna favored it in geeta and rigveda are liked afterthat you are right the transversion occured between two consciosness but if two are god and human inspite of guru and human. If god is one's lord  then everything created by him belongs to him like a father and a small child he needs no permision to enter in house. It is like same relation between guru abd shishya even when God=guru. Its my thinking ofcourse you can do what you want it is not needed everything match in everybody right :)

Comment: If god is one's lord then everything created by him belongs to him like a father and a small child he needs no permision to enter in house.--- God himself has created this system.. Otherwise why did Krishna Rama etc all took Guru Diksha? Why did not they follow ur way? Which scriptures allow chanting mantras without Diksha? Which saints/rishis did not follow this system? So, on what basis you're feeling that your thinking is correct? Anyways, after joining this forum i found out people have very less or no idea about the very core of Hinduism viz-Diksha.. @Fiercelord

Comment: @Rickross Yes, a lot of people here have no idea about Hinduism (that includes me). Almost none here understand Dharma. All we're doing is thinking and intepreting scriptures from the western lenses. Adhyatmik unnati will not happen unless we starting interpreting scriptures from the Dharmic point of view (and this applies to me as well).

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury It is not  a crime to be like that.. anyways u can take Diksha .. ur sense of Dharma will improve.. i have always observed initiated people have more correct and mature thinking than the uninitiated ones.. and Bengal has a great culture of Gurus, Yogis, Dikshas..so, it is not that difficult for u to get initiated.

Comment: @Rickross Well, I guess I have to perform the Vratyasoma ritual and also convince my parents.

Comment: @Fiercelord Bro, I hope that u did not find my comments as harsh and my intention was not to offend u or any one else :)

Comment: @Rickross it's ok now you said in what you believe i in what i ofcource i was thinking one thing your quotes say ladies should stay away from ritual etc but vedic richas are itself written by females that is the reason i do not believe in smritis and messed up with you so,if you are hurt by anything **i am too sory**. Those acts like melting tin in ears ooof.... its so bad and against vedas so sorry again. I thought that shudra was a caste from how much i read and is birthly but this thinking deffrencition is not to do anything with our frienship. :)

Answer (score 3):

In the language of the Smritis, one who's not initiated into the Gayatri is a Sudra or a Vratya and both are equal as far as rights regarding rituals, chanting Vedic Mantras are concerned.

But, i have read in a book (which is not a scripture but based on them), that if a Sudra (basically take it to mean an uninitiated person and not something derogatory) recites certain Vedic Mantras OMkara, Swaha, Savitri, Vashat etc then he becomes an outcaste immediately. So, this would suggest, that he can remedy that by some easy means.

But, the verses i find in the Smritis are not saying the same. They say the Sudra needs to be punished severely by the king. So, in short, i could not find any expiation measures as such.

> By following his own religion even a S'udra enjoys the celestial
>   region. Another's religion should be renounced like the most beautiful
>   wife of another person. (18)
>
> The S'udra, who engages in the recitation [of the Gayatri and the
>   offering of oblations to the Sacred Fire, should be killed by the king
>   ; for by that he becomes the destroyer of the kingdom as the water is
>   of fire. (19)
>
> Recitation [of the Gayatri austerity, and journeys. to sacred places,
>   adoption of a Sannyasa-lite, practice of Mantrams and adoration of
>   Deities, these six bring about the fall of women and S'udras. (135)
>
> *Atri Smriti*

Something similar says the Gautama Smriti:

> If a Sudra uses abusive language or 18 n.), the part of his body used
>   for the crime should be chopped off. 2 If he has sex with an Arya
>   woman, his penis should be cut off and all his property confiscated; 3
>   if the woman had a guardian, then, in addition to the above, he shall
>   be executed. 4And if he listens in on a vedic recitation, his ears
>   shall be filled with molten tin or lac; 5if he repeats it, his tongue
>   shall be cut off; 6if he commits it to memory, his body shall be split
>   asunder
>
> *Gautama Smriti 11.31.*

Comment: Therefore I should be killed...

Comment: I personally do not believe in such extreme instructions.. but that said, initiation into a mantra is without doubt important.. without Diksha, no Purascharana, and without Purascharana no Mantra Siddhi..those might have been just said to frighten people from indulging in the act. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: But why frighten?

Comment: That act might have some bad effect which are unseen to us.. that's why may be..but i do not believe in the punishments.. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury